# an alternative form for $\operatorname{Li}_2$

Tags: calculus

In order to solve the following integral we follow these steps :

$$I =\int_{-\infty}^b \sigma(x)\ln\sigma(x) dx$$
where $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

1- the u-sub : $$\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \Rightarrow \frac{d\sigma}{dx}= \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} = (\frac{1}{\sigma}-1)\sigma^2 = \sigma-\sigma^2 \Rightarrow dx = \frac{d\sigma}{\sigma-\sigma^2} \Rightarrow I = \int_{0}^{\sigma(b)}\frac{\ln\sigma}{1-\sigma}d\sigma = \operatorname{Li}_2(1-\sigma(b))$$

since $0 < \sigma(b)=b' < 1 < 2$ we have :

$$\ln b' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n} \Rightarrow I = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\int_{0}^{\sigma(b)}(\sigma-1)^{n-1} d\sigma =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1-\sigma(b))^n - 1}{n^2} $$
$$\Rightarrow \operatorname{ Li}_2(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k - 1}{k^2} \ \ \ (?)$$

where have I gone wrong?

and for the second part what is the function that minimizes the following integral :
$$I =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sigma(f(x))\ln\sigma(f(x)) dx$$

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{\sigma(b)}\frac{\ln(t)}{1-t}\, dt=\operatorname{Li}_2(1-\sigma(b))\mathbf{-\operatorname{Li}_2(1)}$$

Comment: @KStarGamer thanks and what about the second part? and shouldn't that be $+Li_2(1)$?since the lower bound for dilogarithm in that way is 1? then it would make sense because $Li_2(1) = \zeta(2)$

Comment: No? If both sides are equal to $I$, then of course the final sum you get agrees and it is indeed $\operatorname{Li}_2(z)-\zeta(2)$.

Comment: @KStarGamer yes I am talking about the addition to final result to get $Li_2(x)$